# Deserialize enum into object with string attribute

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I'm currently trying to deserialize an enum value from a json to an object containing a string(where the enum value should end up).

Example:
Domain class

```
public class Person {
private UUID personId;
private Occupation occupation;

}
```

Occupation class:

```
public class Occupation {
private String occupationType;

}
```

The code I am running is:

```
PersonResponse personResponse = JsonConverter.fromJson(message.getPayload(), new TypeReference<Person>() {
    });
```

And the JSON is:

```
{"personId":"719e622e-6e00-4e84-b748-739f95d7c0fa", "occupationType":"STATE_EMPLOYEE"
```

Basically, I want my STATE_EMPLOYEE.name() value to end up in a usable object of the Occupation class. As it is now it tries to deserialize the value STATE_EMPLOYEE into an object of the Occupation class, which obviously doesn't work.

Is there a way for me to return an object like this? I don't want to change my Person object to hold an OccupationType enum because it has a load of other stuff as well.

The error I receive is:

```
 Can not construct instance of person.package.Occupation: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('STATE_EMPLOYEE')
```

It basically fails trying to put my enum value into my Occupation object containing the string. (Where I want my thing to be).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just write enum class OccupationType with value State_EMPLOYEE and gson would parse it.
If you would have some problems in...understanding what I'm trying to say, I'll provide code.

Comment: Does `Occupation` contain any other fields?

Comment: Yes it does, I simplified the example a little bit.

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko I updated my post with the error I receive. You mean I should just make my "String" in my "Occupation" object into an enum and it will work?

Comment: nope, after u said that u simplified example, my comment is wrong. Could you provide full example?

@PrinceofSweden according to info from error, field occupation should be String type not Occupation, because of scheme of your json answer. Try it. If it would work you can map your data to proper models with some mapper.

Comment: There are plenty of json APIs for Java. There are at least two that I know of that have a class called `JsonConverter` with a `fromJson` method, but neither matches the parameters you are passing. So to me it's not clear what `JsonConverter` is or what libraries or custom classes you are using. Please provide a [MCVE], including any imports, and specify any third party tools you use. Depending on what you're using, there are options to create and provide custom type adapters that can convert a String value to your enum type. But without the aforementioned information, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating my own custom Deserializer.